# Auto Switch to external monitor [only] on startup

Tags: startup, external-monitor

I broke my notebook's display a while ago, but it still works fine with an external monitor apart from that.
I have always used (2x) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to switch from the built-in screen to additionally and then exclusively the external monitor.
Now that laptop would do fine to replace my grandpa's obsolete Desktop PC, but for that I would like it to switch to the external monitor on every startup (after every shutdown, reboot) automatically.
Any script, program to do that?

Any help is much appreciated!

Markus

Comment: Doesn't it do that already? My laptop always uses the external monitor exclusively. I keep it closed at all time, and it uses the monitor from the GRUB screen onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch between monitors, I use [xrandr](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/RandR/). A nice GUI for xrandr is ARandR, which is in the repos as well. An example xrandr command would look like this:
`xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --off --output DisplayPort-0 --off --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --off`
In this case, I would only use the DVI-0 port to display my desktop. Tweak this command to fit your needs. Then, put it into a .sh file, chmod +x it and  make sure it will be run on startup.
Note that ARandR has an option to export the current configuration into a skript, which can be very useful.